# Why is quantity++; not the same as print(quantity++);? Is this a gotcha?

Tags: dart, math, numbers, addition, integer-arithmetic

Example code:

```
void main() {
  int quantity = 300;
  print(quantity++); // 300
}
```

I would have thought quantity would now equal 301?

```
void main() {
  int quantity = 300;
  quantity++;
  print(quantity); // 301
  print(quantity++); // 301 >> In this case ++ does nothing??
}
```

Seems to work fine though. Why does it not work as part of a print statement? For example `print(quantity+1);` works fine, so why doesn't `print(quantity++);`?

What is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quantity++ means use the value of quantity, then increment it.
If you did
print(quantity++)
print(quantity)
you'd see the value has changed.
Use ++quantity if you want the value incremented before you use it

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you.

Comment: The postfix-`++` (`quantity++`) is also called *post-increment*, to signify that you increment the value *after* getting the value, and prefix-`++` (`++quantity`) is called *pre-increment* to signify that you increment it before getting the value. The concept, and the syntax used by Dart and many other languages, goes (at least) back to the C programming language.